# How to check two enum has same value, or typesafe way to use both?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two typescript enum that values are same.

```
enum A{
  ONE: "ONE",
  TWO: "TWO",
}
```

```
enum B{
  ONE: "ONE",
  TWO: "TWO",
}
```

And value is type of enum A and function's parameter is enum B type. I want to give A to function parameter. I know that I can acheive this with type casting.

```
(param as unknown) as B // param is enum A
```

But I want to avoid type casting and unknown conversion as much as possible. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the type of the argument of the function that uses the enum value:

```
function useEnum(enumValue: `${A}`) {}
```

It now accepts any `string` value that matches the values of the `A` enum.

```
// works fine
useEnum(A.ONE)
useEnum(A.TWO)
useEnum(B.ONE)
useEnum(B.TWO)
```

If `B` has any additional values that `A` does not have, they would not be accepted as arguments.

```
enum B {
  ONE = "ONE",
  TWO = "TWO",
  THREE = "THREE"
}

// error: Argument of type 'B.THREE' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ONE" | "TWO"'.
useEnum(B.THREE)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=17&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUDyA5AolAvFARBpvgDTJQAqA6qrgdavogL6KKiRQBCC5RdhLKXIMBDYSgoAJAEqZsefNLnEWbAGZgQAYwAuASwD2IKGADOwTOAgAKDhABqAQwA2YYAC4oAAwAk8GGZvAEoEVkQAegioAHdDACcAazModX0QYERzS2sbGAA6ImCsiytIPPyGYuyy2y5CrGrS3PqqtiioYHj4hK8YeIBzSFBdKEN1KF0ATwAHYCgAclbZeQWofRSQQ1GnMzN9AZAnACMXed1DKBmneKcIYF0usYnpucXBYigAH3oafAX8iUcuVlipgkA)

---

Keep in mind that this breaks if the enums are using numbers instead of strings.

```
enum A {
  ONE,
  TWO
}

function useEnum(enumValue: `${A}`) {}

// Argument of type 'A.ONE' is not assignable to parameter of type '"0" | "1"'
useEnum(A.ONE)
```

This can be fixed by adding a generic type `T` to the function.

```
enum A {
  ONE = "ONE",
  TWO = 2
}

enum B {
  ONE = "ONE",
  TWO = 2,
  THREE = "THREE"
}

type IsAValue<T extends string | number> =
  `${T}` extends `${A}` ? T : A

function useEnum<T extends string | number>(enumValue: IsAValue<T>) {}

// works fine
useEnum(A.ONE)
useEnum(A.TWO)
useEnum(B.ONE)
useEnum(B.TWO)

// error: Argument of type 'B.THREE' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'
useEnum(B.THREE)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKUDyA5AolAvFARBpvgDTJQAqA6qrlAEyIC%20iiokUAQguUXYVlLlqtPPTIoKACQBKmbHnzS5xZqwAuATwAOwKAEkAzjABqAQwA2YYAB4KUYAA91oACaGoh9QCcAliABzKAAfKHAIACNgbwA%20XHIAAwASeAomBIdnNw9k%20Bh0qAB%20SigALlhWADMwEABjdV8AexAoMENgTHC7TJcQd08ffyDQ8KjYgAp2CHMrYHKjU0trOxiASgQWRAB6LagAd0bvAGsPSv9gRDaO8PGYADoiVcv2zshbu5Enq9eIcc4HrBfF43f6fVg7BzebyHcowbwBSCgdRQRqVKBaXRQADkoNk8ixUF8HhAjWRZkMhl8ARAZgiFj06kaUG0Zm8ZggwBc3hRaIxeixMCxz2ub1xKlWQA)